# Перезапуск Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть два Activity, на первом Activity при открытии воспроизводится анимация. При переходе со второго Activity на первое, (при помощи кнопки Back) анимация не воспроизводиться снова. Как сделать что бы была анимация? Возможно ли сделать так что бы первое активити перезапускалась снова. Или не хранилось в памяти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так я полагаю

```
private void showAnimation(){
    //анимация
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showAnimation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет про анимацию появления активити `overridePendingTransition` то можно сделать так:

```
public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,R.anim.slide_in_right);
 }
```

или так:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,R.anim.slide_in_right);
}
```